# for loop output not showing up

Tags: c++, loops, struct, for-loop

This code accepts input for student identification and their current balances. -999 is typed as the A-Number to break the loop or it will run until 30 students have been entered.

My for loop at the bottom of the program is supposed to list the entered A-Number, Student Name, and their Balance in opposite order that it is inputted. Nothing is being listed though. Just the header of A-Number:, Student:, and Balance:

I know there is a simple explanation but I just can't think and I'm hoping someone can point it out for me...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    const int maxStudents = 30;
    struct Students{
        string studentName;
        int aNumber;
        double outstandingBalance;};

    Students students[maxStudents];

    int count = 0;
    for( ; count < maxStudents-1; count++)
    {
        cout<<"\nA-Number:";
        cin>>students[count].aNumber;
        if(students[count].aNumber == -999)
                break;
            cout<<"Student Name:";
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin,students[count].studentName);
            cout<<"\nOutstanding Balance:";
            cin>>students[count].outstandingBalance;
    }

    cout<<setw(20)<<"\nA-Number "<<"Name "<<"Balance ";

    for( ; count >= maxStudents-1; count--)
        cout<<setw(20)<<students[count].aNumber<<" "<<students[count].studentName<<" "<<students[count].outstandingBalance<<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "please *bare* with me" - But I don't even know you!

Comment: Supposedly you want to iterate from the current count down as long as it  bigger or equal to zero: you count will never be bigger than the maximun number of students.

Comment: iostreams are generally buffered, so you might want to have a look at flush to make sure the output gets written when you expect it too....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second loop never runs because `count` is already too small (`count == maxStudents - 1` if the loop ran all the way through, so you might get one pass).  Your loop condition needs to be `count >= 0`.

Comment: Thanks I knew it was something as simple as that but staring at all the code is a blur to me right now.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop at the end is simply wrong. Use:

```
for (int i=count; i=>0; i--)
```

Look carefully if you want to show the (i)th record in the reversed order. Then your loop should start from the **number of Students**. How long should it run? As long as your 0th record has not been reached. With each succession, you reduce i by 1. And finally use this **"i"** (counter) to use as the record number your trying to display.

A future advice is to use terms such as DISPLAY or COUT instead of LIST. and LIST also refers to Linked Lists and a lot more other things.